# DTO Generator for EF 4 Entity model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, t4, dto

Is it possible to write t4 template ( or if it already exists ) which will be able to generate DTO classes based on the data in the *.edmx file?

I have to write DTO classes for the current project, and this process is kinda tiresome.

What I trying to acquire is to get DTO classes which will have scalar properties defined as simple auto properties, and navigation parameters as incapsulated instances of other DTO classes.

Example :

```
public class SomeClassDTO
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }        

    public OtherClassDTO SomeProperty {get;set;}

    public IList<AnotherClassDTO> Objects {get;set;}
}
```

This is a good starting point, what is more desirable may look like following sample:

```
/// <summary>
/// Employee details DTO.
/// </summary>
public class EmployeeDetailsDTO
{
    [Key] 
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    ...

    public long? PhotoId { get; set; }

    // Home address properties.


    public string HomeAddressAddressLine1 { get; set; } // This is just name of field, not flattened list 
    public string HomeAddressAddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddressAddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddressPostcode { get; set; }
    public short? HomeAddressCountryId { get; set; }
    public long? HomeAddressCountyId { get; set; }
    public long? HomeAddressTownId { get; set; }


    public short? HomeTelephoneCountryId { get; set; }        
    public string HomeTelephoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public string HomeTelephoneExtension { get; set; }


    public short? PersonalMobileCountryId { get; set; }      
    public string PersonalMobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string PersonalMobileExtension { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see this is a flatten DTO which represent composite structure and may be injected back to entities through ValueInjector SameNameFlat/UnFlat injections.

This is the ultimate goal, though any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: DTO is specialized object for single purpose and in most cases its creation cannot be automatized because it usually contains additional properties or miss some properties from the entity (it is not 1:1 mapping of the entity) so creating DTOs which are just copy of your entities looks more like a problem in the architecture. Even your recursive T4 template can add properties which you do not need. DTO should pass only properties you need for the operation where DTO is used.

Comment: Yes, sure, this t4 stuff just makes it easier. At least I don't have to write skeleton by hand for each dto that I creating. When I get scanned class, I can cut it in pieces as I want to.

Answer (score 14):

I recently published an Entity Framework DTO Generator named EntitiesToDTOs at CodePlex, it is free and open source, and it is used as an AddIn for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I think it will be of help for you.

Go to http://entitiestodtos.codeplex.com to download it, and let me know what you think ;)

Answer (score 2):

finally am able to create a item template for C# language which will create DTO classes for you in VS 2010. Kindly follow the link:
http://www.stepupframeworks.com/Home/products/entity-to-dto-creator/

Answer (score 1):

Please look on the link: http://www.insidelogic.nl/Blog/tabid/146/EntryId/4/Create-DTO-Data-transfer-objects-from-an-Entity-Framework-edmx-file.aspx
Maybe it will help you.

Comment: unfortunately the link to source is broken

Comment: Web archive got a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20090413084946/http://www.insidelogic.nl/Blog/tabid/146/EntryId/4/Create-DTO-Data-transfer-objects-from-an-Entity-Framework-edmx-file.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It appeared much easier than I thought. If anybody is interested there is a t4 template for recursive scan through entity tree:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
 output extension=".cs"#><#
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this, 1);
MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);

string inputFile = @"D:\Projects\Empresa\CTM_Empresa\trunk\CTM.Empresa.Logic\DataModel\CTM.Empresa.Database.edmx";

string entityName = @"Email";

bool printNavigationLists = false;

MetadataWorkspace metadataWorkspace = null;
bool allMetadataLoaded = loader.TryLoadAllMetadata(inputFile, out metadataWorkspace);
EdmItemCollection ItemCollection = (EdmItemCollection)metadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSpace);

string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();

EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);

RecursiveEntityProcessor.code = code;
RecursiveEntityProcessor.ItemCollection = ItemCollection;
RecursiveEntityProcessor.metaData = ef;

// Emit Entity Types
foreach (EntityType entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().Where(it => it.Name == entityName))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");

    var result = new List<PropertyCustomData>();    

    RecursiveEntityProcessor.GetEntityPropertyNames(result, entity.Name , 2 , "");  

    //WriteEntityTypeSerializationInfo(entity, ItemCollection, code, ef);
#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
<# 
    foreach (PropertyCustomData property in result)
    {       
        #>
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets <#=code.Escape(property.PropertyName)#>.
    /// </summary>
    <#=Accessibility.ForProperty(property.PropertyDefenition)#> <#=code.Escape(property.PropertyDefenition.TypeUsage)#> <#=code.Escape(property.PropertyName)#> { get; set; }
<#

    }    
}#> 
}

<#+ 

    public class PropertyCustomData
    {
        public EdmProperty PropertyDefenition { get; set; }

        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class RecursiveEntityProcessor
    {       
        public static CodeGenerationTools code;

        public static EdmItemCollection ItemCollection;

        public static MetadataTools metaData;

        public static EntityType FindByName(string entityName)
        {
            return ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().Single(it => it.Name == entityName);
        }

        public static void GetEntityPropertyNames(IList<PropertyCustomData> result, string entityName, int recursiveDepth, string currentPrefix, bool canPrintPrimaryKeys = true)
        {           
            if (recursiveDepth > 0 )
            {
                EntityType entity = FindByName(entityName);

                foreach (EdmProperty edmProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity))
                {
                    if (metaData.IsKey(edmProperty) && !canPrintPrimaryKeys)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    result.Add(new PropertyCustomData { PropertyDefenition = edmProperty, PropertyName = currentPrefix + code.Escape(edmProperty) });
                }

                foreach (NavigationProperty navProperty in entity.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == entity))
                {
                    if (navProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity != RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
                    {
                        string childEntityName = navProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType().Name;

                        GetEntityPropertyNames(result, childEntityName, recursiveDepth - 1, currentPrefix + code.Escape(navProperty), false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

#>
```

this template produces code like in last example of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update for Visual Studio 2012 T4 Template to generate a simple DTO objects on the base of an existing EDMX file. It skips navigational properties and only generates simple properties.

Using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) I was able to copy my POCO data into the DTO objects. 
These are serializiable and can be transported as XML. When rebuilding the objects a the target site it is possible to attach them to the dbContext and call DetectChanges(). 
References will be fixed thereafter.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>
<#


const string inputFile = @"../Model/ModelTest.edmx";
var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
var ef = new MetadataTools(this);
var typeMapper = new TypeMapper(code, ef, textTransform.Errors);
var fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
var itemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
var codeStringGenerator = new CodeStringGenerator(code, typeMapper, ef);

if (!typeMapper.VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(typeMapper.GetAllGlobalItems(itemCollection), inputFile))
{
    return string.Empty;
}

WriteHeader(codeStringGenerator, fileManager);

foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + "Dto.cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(false)#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
{
<#
    var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>
}
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}

foreach (var complex in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<ComplexType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(complex.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(false, false)#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#>
{
<#

    var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(complex);
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach(var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>
}
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}
fileManager.Process();
#>

<#+

public void WriteHeader(CodeStringGenerator codeStringGenerator, EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager)
{
    fileManager.StartHeader();
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// <#=GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1")#>
//
// <#=GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2")#>
// <#=GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3")#>
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(true)#>
<#+
    fileManager.EndBlock();
}

public void BeginNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    var codeNamespace = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeNamespace))
    {
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(codeNamespace)#>
{
<#+
        PushIndent("    ");
    }
}

public void EndNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(code.VsNamespaceSuggestion()))
    {
        PopIndent();
#>
}
<#+
    }
}

public const string TemplateId = "CSharp_DbContext_Types_EF5";

public class CodeStringGenerator
{
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly TypeMapper _typeMapper;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public CodeStringGenerator(CodeGenerationTools code, TypeMapper typeMapper, MetadataTools ef)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(typeMapper, "typeMapper");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");

        _code = code;
        _typeMapper = typeMapper;
        _ef = ef;
    }

    public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "[DataMember()] {0} {1} {2} {3} {{get; {4}set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
    }


    public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
            return string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "[DataContract()]\r\n{0} {1}partial class {2}Dto{3}",
                Accessibility.ForType(entity),
                _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
                _code.Escape(entity),
                _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }


    public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
    {
        return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
            ? string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}using System;" +Environment.NewLine+
                "using System.Runtime.Serialization;{1}" +
                "{2}",
                inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
                includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
                inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
            : "";
    }
}

public class TypeMapper
{
    private const string ExternalTypeNameAttributeName = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration:ExternalTypeName";

    private readonly System.Collections.IList _errors;
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public TypeMapper(CodeGenerationTools code, MetadataTools ef, System.Collections.IList errors)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");
        ArgumentNotNull(errors, "errors");

        _code = code;
        _ef = ef;
        _errors = errors;
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, null,  null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, null, modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, bool? isNullable, string modelNamespace)
    {
        if (edmType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var collectionType = edmType as CollectionType;
        if (collectionType != null)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ICollection<{0}>", GetTypeName(collectionType.TypeUsage, modelNamespace));
        }

        var typeName = _code.Escape(edmType.MetadataProperties
                                .Where(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName)
                                .Select(p => (string)p.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
            ?? (modelNamespace != null && edmType.NamespaceName != modelNamespace ?
                _code.CreateFullName(_code.EscapeNamespace(edmType.NamespaceName), _code.Escape(edmType)) :
                _code.Escape(edmType));

        if (edmType is StructuralType)
        {
            return typeName;
        }

        if (edmType is SimpleType)
        {
            var clrType = UnderlyingClrType(edmType);
            if (!IsEnumType(edmType))
            {
                typeName = _code.Escape(clrType);
            }

            return clrType.IsValueType && isNullable == true ?
                String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Nullable<{0}>", typeName) :
                typeName;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("edmType");
    }

    public Type UnderlyingClrType(EdmType edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        var primitiveType = edmType as PrimitiveType;
        if (primitiveType != null)
        {
            return primitiveType.ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        if (IsEnumType(edmType))
        {
            return GetEnumUnderlyingType(edmType).ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        return typeof(object);
    }



    public bool IsEnumType(GlobalItem edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        return edmType.GetType().Name == "EnumType";
    }

    public PrimitiveType GetEnumUnderlyingType(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        return (PrimitiveType)enumType.GetType().GetProperty("UnderlyingType").GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public string CreateLiteral(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(TimeSpan))
        {
            return _code.CreateLiteral(value);
        }

        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "new TimeSpan({0})", ((TimeSpan)value).Ticks);
    }

    public bool VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(IEnumerable<string> types, string sourceFile)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(types, "types");
        ArgumentNotNull(sourceFile, "sourceFile");

        var hash = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (types.Any(item => !hash.Add(item)))
        {
            _errors.Add(
                new CompilerError(sourceFile, -1, -1, "6023",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, GetResourceString("Template_CaseInsensitiveTypeConflict"))));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



    public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToGenerate<T>(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection) where T: EdmType
    {
        return itemCollection
            .OfType<T>()
            .Where(i => !i.MetadataProperties.Any(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName))
            .OrderBy(i => i.Name);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllGlobalItems(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return itemCollection
            .Where(i => i is EntityType || i is ComplexType || i is EntityContainer || IsEnumType(i))
            .Select(g => GetGlobalItemName(g));
    }

    public string GetGlobalItemName(GlobalItem item)
    {
        if (item is EdmType)
        {
            return ((EdmType)item).Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((EntityContainer)item).Name;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }
}

public class EdmMetadataLoader
{
    private readonly IDynamicHost _host;
    private readonly System.Collections.IList _errors;

    public EdmMetadataLoader(IDynamicHost host, System.Collections.IList errors)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(host, "host");
        ArgumentNotNull(errors, "errors");

        _host = host;
        _errors = errors;
    }

    public IEnumerable<GlobalItem> CreateEdmItemCollection(string sourcePath)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(sourcePath, "sourcePath");

        if (!ValidateInputPath(sourcePath))
        {
            return new EdmItemCollection();
        }

        var schemaElement = LoadRootElement(_host.ResolvePath(sourcePath));
        if (schemaElement != null)
        {
            using (var reader = schemaElement.CreateReader())
            {
                IList<EdmSchemaError> errors;
                var itemCollection = MetadataItemCollectionFactory.CreateEdmItemCollection(new[] { reader }, out errors);

                ProcessErrors(errors, sourcePath);

                return itemCollection;
            }
        }
        return new EdmItemCollection();
    }

    public string GetModelNamespace(string sourcePath)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(sourcePath, "sourcePath");

        if (!ValidateInputPath(sourcePath))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var model = LoadRootElement(_host.ResolvePath(sourcePath));
        if (model == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var attribute = model.Attribute("Namespace");
        return attribute != null ? attribute.Value : "";
    }

    private bool ValidateInputPath(string sourcePath)
    {
        if (sourcePath == "$" + "edmxInputFile" + "$")
        {
            _errors.Add(
                new CompilerError(_host.TemplateFile ?? sourcePath, 0, 0, string.Empty,
                    GetResourceString("Template_ReplaceVsItemTemplateToken")));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public XElement LoadRootElement(string sourcePath)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(sourcePath, "sourcePath");

        var root = XElement.Load(sourcePath, LoadOptions.SetBaseUri | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
        return root.Elements()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Runtime")
            .Elements()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ConceptualModels")
            .Elements()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Schema")
            .FirstOrDefault()
                ?? root;
    }

    private void ProcessErrors(IEnumerable<EdmSchemaError> errors, string sourceFilePath)
    {
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            _errors.Add(
                new CompilerError(
                    error.SchemaLocation ?? sourceFilePath,
                    error.Line,
                    error.Column,
                    error.ErrorCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    error.Message)
                {
                    IsWarning = error.Severity == EdmSchemaErrorSeverity.Warning
                });
        }
    }


}

public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(T arg, string name) where T : class
{
    if (arg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}

private static readonly Lazy<System.Resources.ResourceManager> ResourceManager =
    new Lazy<System.Resources.ResourceManager>(
        () => new System.Resources.ResourceManager("System.Data.Entity.Design", typeof(MetadataItemCollectionFactory).Assembly),  true);

public static string GetResourceString(string resourceName)
{
    ArgumentNotNull(resourceName, "resourceName");

    return ResourceManager.Value.GetString(resourceName, null);
}

#>
```